# Substring in search with Django

Tags: python, html, django

How I can do a search for substring for a filename using Django

views.py

```
def search(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    find_entries = list()

    search_box = request.POST.get("q").capitalize()

    if search_box in entries:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"wiki/{search_box}")
    
    for entry in entries:
        if search_box in entry:
            find_entries.append(entry)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
                "search_result": find_entries,
                "search": search_box
            })
        else:
            print(f'{find_entries}')
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {"no_result": f"No results for {search_box}"})
```

search.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    search results
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for result in search_result %}
        <li><a href=wiki/{{ result }}>{{ result }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <h1>{{ no_result }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

i tried it but only return a result for example if I search for `'d'` it only return `django` and then stop the for loop without return another values like node for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exiting for loop after first successful iteration. Change the code as following:

```
for entry in entries:
    if search_box in entry:
        find_entries.append(entry)
    else:
        print(f'{find_entries}')
if find_entries:
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
       "search_result": find_entries,
       "search": search_box
    })
...
```